# Bootstrap navigation on active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I am trying to change the background-color of the  list Item on my menu(has dropdown submenu on it)when active. the list item is changing color, but the anchor inside it having different color instead

```
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Item1</a >
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SubItem4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my css:

```
  .navbar-nav > li {
   background-color:black;
   }   
  .navbar-nav > li a:active{
    background-color:white !important;
   }
```

Comment: can you share an example on jsfiddle/plnkr/codepen or anywhere else for reference?